# Thick refinements of covers

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, and let ${\cal U}$ be an open cover. We say that ${\cal U}$ is *thick* if for all $x\in X$ we have $$|\{V\in {\cal U}: x\in V\}| = |X|.$$
Is there a Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ with $|X|>1$ and an open cover ${\cal U}$ of $X$ such that every [refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)#Refinement) of ${\cal U}$ is thick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible for any $T_1$ space $X$. For suppose $X$ is $T_1$ and $\mathcal U$ is an open cover of $X$, and fix $x \in X$. If $U$ is some member of $\mathcal U$ containing $x$, then $\{U\} \cup \{V \setminus \{x\} : V \in \mathcal U,\, V \neq U\}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal U$, but it is not thick because only one set in this refinement contains $x$.

Comment: Of course! For the question it suffices to handle only one point, not all points, as in my answer. I wonder, however, about generalizations of the theorem in my answer to uncountable spaces.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Good question! A similar question was already asked by Dominic here on MathOverflow (my assumption is that thinking about it further partially motivated this question) -- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298639/minimal-refinements-of-open-covers-of-t-2-spaces?rq=1. My answer to that question shows that the countability assumption in your theorem is indispensable.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer. I would like to note merely that this is not possible in a countable space.

**Theorem.** In any countable Hausdorff space $X$ and any open
cover $U$, there is a refinement of $U$ to an open cover $U'$ such
that every point $x\in X$ is in only finitely many elements of
$U'$.

**Proof.** Enumerate the space as $X=\{x_n\mid n\in\omega\}$. At
each stage $n$, consider $x_n$, and let $U_n$ be a set in $U$ with
$x_n\in U_n$. Let $U_n'$ be a refinement of $U_n$ that excludes the
points $x_k$ for $k<n$. This is possible by the separation axiom. Let $U'$ be the set of all $U_n'$. This
refines the original cover, and $x_n$ is an element of at most $n+1$ many
elements of $U'$, since it is excluded after stage $n$. $\Box$

Comment: Thanks Joel for this partial answer! I was thinking about how to carry on the induction to larger cardinals, but it seems like one would get a "predecessor problem" (in your argument, you have only finitely many $k<n$).

Comment: I guess this argument uses only $T_1$ and not fully Hausdorff.

Comment: Spaces satisfying the conclusion of your theorem are called *metacompact*. The ordinal $\omega_1$ is not metacompact since countably compact metacompact spaces are compact.

Comment: By the way, $\omega_1$ is not meta-Lindelof either (I believe for ordinals, meta-Lindelof and metacompact coincide). So the theorem cannot be pushed up even changing "finitely many" by "countably many".